# document management private users

Tags: document-management, ocr

i am searching for a document management system that supports:

1. can bulk scan documents
2. automatic OCR of scanned documents
3. data storage on my local HD / external server of my choice
4. automatic backups (not that important)
5. proper full text search
6. document versioning
7. (automatic) document categorization or tagging
8. platform independent
9. free

Do you know a document management system fulfilling these requirements?

Answer (score 5):

You may use LogicalDOC http://www.logicaldoc.com in combination with a multi-function printer or a document scanner.

In this way, the printer or the scanner might scan the documents and produce the PDF files.

The MFP (multi-functional-printer) will place the PDF documents on a network shared folder.

Subsequently LogicalDOC Business can acquire the PDF files from the network shared folder and proceed with the indexing of documents.

So LogicalDOC business may fulfill the following requisites:
2, 3, 4 (you can configure easily the backup), 5, 6, 8

With regard to the automatic categorization of the documents it is possible to define multiple import folders and specify a document type for each folder, so with a little effort you can enable the automatic categorization of documents

Answer (score 0):

Also might be interested in other applications, here you have a complete list:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

From what I know the most popular are Alfresco, Nuxeo and OpenKM ( alfresco.com, nuxeo.com and openkm.com ). Probably for your needs OpenKM might be the best option, because is quite easy to get it started and it has an small learning curve for your users. Alfresco and Nuxeo at the present are more complete and complex solutions ( it mean more time and pain for getting it running ).